# Python HTTP POST requests serialized in AVRO

Tags: python, http, httprequest, apache-nifi, avro

I am trying to send data with an python script to Apache NiFi via HTTP requests. I can send it in JSON format without problems, but I am trying to do it serialized in AVRO.
One of my tries is in the code below (the output of the code is Response[405] at the requests* line).

```
import requests
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

json = {'fname':'Foo','lname':'Bar','sex':'m','year':1900}
SCHEMA_PATH = r"<PATH_TO_AVSC>\user.avsc"
URL = <URL_TO_NIFI_LISTENHTTP>
schema = avro.schema.parse(open(SCHEMA_PATH, "rb").read())
import io
buf = io.BytesIO()
writer = DataFileWriter(buf, DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.append(json)
writer.flush()
buf.seek(0)
msg = buf.read()
requests.post(URL, data = msg)
```

Is it possible to send an AVRO serialized messages without creating and sending files, similar to my try, and where I go wrong?

Is there any big advantage by using AVRO instead of JSON? At the end, I could transfer the messages as JSON, but I would like to accomplish it in AVRO.

Comment: + thanks. above method worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to send an AVRO serialized messages without creating and sending files, similar to my try, and where I go wrong?

The result of serializing data in avro is just a binary string so you should be able to send over that binary string to the server and have the server deserialize it. I'm not sure what your server code is doing, so I can't help explain the 405 error.

> Is there any big advantage by using AVRO instead of JSON? At the end, I could transfer the messages as JSON, but I would like to accomplish it in AVRO.

The amount of data being transferred over the wire should be smaller using Avro (especially if you are sending multiple records at a time). You can decide if the bandwidth difference is significant enough to make it worth it.

Comment: turned out that I am getting the response message because I had 2 ListenHTTP Processors on the same port. After a turned one off, I get an regular "200" response. I have to investigate it a little bit more and spend more time with NiFi...